# CSS transitions not working on jQuery class replace

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I've got a simple jQuery script that changes the class on a `ul` when the page scrolls down 100 px, shifting the menu from centered to `float: right`, with a smooth movement using CSS transitions. Is this possible?

My script:

```
 $(document).on("scroll",function(){
if($(document).scrollTop()>100){
    $("#nav").removeClass("stick-menu-top").addClass("stick-menu");
} else{
    $("#nav").removeClass("stick-menu").addClass("stick-menu-top");
}
});
```

My 2 classes:

```
ul.stick-menu-top { float:none; margin:0 auto; width:614px; padding:17px 0 0; }
ul.stick-menu { float:right; width:614px; padding:17px 0 0; }
```

My CSS animation:

```
    #nav.stick-menu-top, #nav.stick-menu-top a, #nav.stick-menu-top ul, #nav.stick-menu-top li{ transition: all 1s; -moz-transition: all 1s; -webkit-transition: all 1s; -o-transition: all 1s; }
```

I would really appreciate any help with this. You can see the website here: http://www.thoriumdocumentary.com/redesign/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of properties that can be transitioned and be found at the [W3C site](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties), and `float` is not one of them :)

I think the best way to handle the situation would be to remove the floats, and position the menu items by altering `margin-right` or `left` (this one in conjuction with `position:relative` for both menu container and it's parent) with the help of jQuery.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // before the scroll
    $('#menuContainer').css('margin-right',($(window).width() - $('#menuContainer').width())/2 + 'px');

    // after scroll
    $('#menuContainer').css('margin-right',($(window).width() - $('#menuContainer').width()) + 'px');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

add this to the classes:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

if this doesnt work for you you can try jquery ui switchClass():
http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/

Comment: I actually already tried that with no success... It doesn't work for some reason

Comment: hmmm perhaps #nav.stick-menu-top, #nav.stick-menu-top a, #nav.stick-menu-top ul, #nav.stick-menu-top li{ transition: all 1s; -moz-transition: all 1s; -webkit-transition: all 1s; -o-transition: all 1s; } is messing it up?

Comment: I just deleted that out of the stylesheet completely - no effect :(

Comment: in jquery ui, theres something called .switchClass() that animates the changing

Comment: I gave that a try - the switchClass part worked fine - just not the animation!